# Limit permission to only Feature branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

As an admin, how i can restrict any user to create or write only feature/* branch?. I dont want the user to create branch with any other names.

Comment: See [here](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) for information on branch control in bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Not practically. Git branches aren't really distinct from one another in the way that you're probably thinking they are.

What you probably want to do here is use a separate repository for each user's development branch.

Comment: Not really, see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that(though I didn't do that myself).

Take a look at the `.git/hooks/` directory, you can install hooks there. Also if you are using `gitlab`, IIRC, there's a `webhooks` page for you to install hooks for your repos.